# Passkeys with Firefox - Touch your security key to continue

Tags: firefox, security, authentication, passkey

I am trying to log in to Github with Firefox.  When I try to log in, the web page gives me an option to try with a passkey.  When I do that, Firefox displays a dialog box saying "Touch your security key to continue with github.com."  It does not offer any additional instructions about what that means or how to do that.

I'm not sure what I am supposed to do at this point.  What is a "security key" and how do I touch it?  Is a "security key" a separate physical device, or something else?

I have never set up any separate device (e.g., Yubikey etc.), so I am not sure what it is referring to.  Any ideas how to interpret this message from Firefox?  I am using Firefox 122.0.1.  A websearch for "touch your security key to continue" turns up nothing useful.

Comment: What is do you run? On my windows boxen the passkeys are linked to windows hello and it may be a physical security key is the only option for your environment

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, Fedora 39.  Thank you!

Comment: The [source](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/browser/locales/en-US/chrome/browser/browser.properties) calls this message `webauthn.userPresencePrompt`. So this method is perhaps supposed to somehow verify the user's physical presence by your somehow interacting with something. Do you have a passkey or something? Do you use Firefox sync and how do you authenticate?

Comment: @harrymc, thank you.  I'm embarrassed to admit I don't know what a "passkey" is.  I don't have a physical device.  I don't think I use Firefox sync (at least not to my knowledge).

Comment: If you don't have a passkey, why don't you login to `github.com` with the option of user-name & password?

Comment: @harrymc, I do.  After I enter username & password, Github prompts asking for a passkey ("When you are ready, authenticate using the button below. This browser or device is reporting partial passkey support." with a button for "Use passkey")  I'm not familiar with passkeys and don't know how to interpret that.

Comment: This [link](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/authenticating-with-a-passkey/managing-your-passkeys) might jog your memory.

Answer (score -1):

As you might know, GitHub doesn't currently support login by username/password, so your only choice is to have some MFA.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.  Firefox itself cannot act like a Passkey device, extensions like 1Password and LastPass, if an supported extension is not present then a BT device must be present.